# How to update the costs by multiplying with quantity without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select element with options in my html code. There are three different quantities (options): 1,2,3.

Each time an option is clicked I want to update my subtotal cost without refreshing the page.

I'm selecting the total amount using id='total'.

**This is my HTML code:**

```
<td>
    <select>
        <option class="option" value="1">1</option>
        <option class="option" value="2">2</option>
        <option class="option" value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</td>

<td>
    <p id='total'>699</p>
</td>
```

**And this is my Javascript / jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.option').click(function(){
        var total =699;

        $('.option:select').each(function(){
            total*= parseInt($(this).val()); 
        });

        $('#total').html('$'+total);
    });
});
```

Comment: you page get refreshed when oncge triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i prepared this fiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/hd61mvc4/

your js code was not correct (and i also added a class to the HTML select element).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mySelect').change(function(){
        var total =699;
        $('#total').html(total*$(this).val())
    });
});
```

greetings

Comment: you can mark the answer with the green hook to mark your question as solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because there's no `:select` selector in jQuery, and the `each()` is not needed. You also should hook the event handler to the `change` event of the `select` element, not the `click` of the `option`.

You are also attempting to update the value of `total` on each event, which will mean that subsequent calculations are incorrect as they work on the previous result, not the origin al `699` value. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $total = $('#total');
  var originalTotal = $total.data('total');
    
  $('select').change(function() {
    $total.html('$' + (originalTotal * $(this).val()));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option class="option" value="1">1</option>
        <option class="option" value="2">2</option>
        <option class="option" value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="total" data-total="699">$699</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that I amended the logic to read the starting value (ie. `699`) from a `data` attribute in the HTML, instead of a magic number in your JS code. This makes the logic easier to maintain and also more extensible.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
                    <select>
                        <option class="option" value="1">1</option>
                        <option class="option" value="2">2</option>
                        <option class="option" value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

   <td><p id='total'>699</p></td>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('select').on("change",function(){
                var total =699;

                $('select').each(function(){
                    total*= parseInt($(this).val()); 
                });
                $('#total').html('$'+total);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: if you are satistfied with my answer you can mark my question as solved or upvote